# Common tool to run software in cross platform operating systems?

Tags: windows, linux, cross-platform

**Scenario and example**

In Windows, software usually comes with the extension `.exe`. I know I can run `.exe` files in Linux operating systems using third party tools like Wine. Likewise, there may be a separate tool for running Windows files on Mac OSX.

**What I need**

Is it there any cross-platform tool which can do the following:

- Run `.exe` files on Linux & Mac?
- Run Mac OS X software packages on Windows & Linux?
- Run Mac & Linux software packages on Windows?

Comment: Do you know virtual machines?

Comment: @Fractaliste  for running a single tool i cant maintain a vmware image and a extra memory and burden mate,yup aware of vmware,virtual box etc

Comment: If you're *writing* the software, you can look into cross-platform languages (like Java), but taking an existing app and doing this is much, much harder.

Comment: Why would you insist on one tool that does all this?  Why an array of tools X, such that x1 runs A binaries on OS M, x2 runs B binaroes on OS N, ....  Given that each OS simulation is a major exercise in its own right, you are more likely to find this "a single tool".

Answer (score 14):

No, there isn't.

Your best solution would be to use some form of virtualisation on the operating system of your choice to run the various other operating systems you need for running the applications you want within the virtualised guest within your host environment.

Examples of virtualisation software include:

- [VM Ware](http://www.vmware.com/)
- [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
- [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/)

In addition to virtualisation software, you will also need the following:

- A copy of each operating system you intend to run (Windows, Linux, OS X)

Alternatively, it is possible to run many Windows applications in a Linux environment using [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/), which will support the installation and running of a lot of Windows applications within a Linux environment. It is possible to run many Linux non-GUI applications on Windows using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) but this will require recompiling applications from source in order for them to function.